# How can action and reaction forces be equal?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

Suppose that I push an object having a very small mass of 10 grams.

The object accelerates, so does our hand. Since, the mass of the object is less than ours and so is the acceleration then how can it exert an equal force on our hand since $F=ma$?

Comment: What do you mean by “and so is the acceleration “? Acceleration of why? It’s not clear what you are asking

Comment: How is the acceleration of your hand more that the small mass?

Comment: Are you asking how your hand accelerates given the reaction force on it? Your hand is part of your much heavier body. You have to consider the effect of the reaction force on the center of mass of your body, not just your hand. Your hand may have an acceleration equal to that of the 10 gram mass, but your body doesn't. If you were out in space doing this, then your body would move a small amount oppositely to the small mass.

Comment: Also, you are a deformable object.  Your feet can be fixed on the floor while your hand is accelerating.   That complicates the business, and can muddy the analysis.

Comment: @Sam Can it not be?

Answer (score 1):

When you exert a force $F$ on the object having a mass $m$ $(=10 gm)$, then according to Newton's third law of motion, an equal force but in the opposite direction is exerted on your hand.

The object moves with an acceleration $a=\frac{F}m$, whereas your hand (assuming it's mass to be $M$ and ignoring any other force acting on the arm-hand system) moves with an acceleration $a'=\frac{F}M$ opposite to the direction of motion of the object.

You don't actually start moving backwards due to the opposite force $F$ since it's not enough to overcome the friction between your feet and the ground.

The fact that the mass of the object is smaller than ours does not imply that a reaction force cannot exist. Whenever you apply force to any object (no matter what it's mass), there will always be a reaction force that is exactly equal but opposite in direction.

Comment: *"whereas your hand (assuming it's mass to be M) moves with an acceleration a′=FM opposite to the direction of motion of the object. "* No, the acceleration of the hand, if retaining contact with the object, is the same as the object. The net force on the hand is the sum of the force provided by the arm (forward) and the force from the object (backward). This net force on the hand is much larger than the force the hand exerts on the object.

Comment: Are you saying that the force that our arm exerts and the magnitude of the force applied on the object are different? That only a portion of the total applied force is exerted on the object? @BillN

Comment: I'm saying the the net force on the hand/arm system is different from the force the hand applies to the object. The place where the forces form a Newton's 3rd law pair is at the interface of the hand and the object. The object exerts a single force on the hand. It is equal and opposite to the force the hand exerts on the object. But there are other forces acting on the hand. Newton's 3rd Law doesn't apply to NET force on things. A single force involves a single interaction with one other object. That single force has a Newton 3rd Law partner. @Quantum-meatball

Answer (score 1):

First let’s understand what actually $ \vec F = m \vec a$ means. If you push on light stationary object and on a heavy stationary object you will find them moving with different speeds (I’m assuming friction to be absent and same force is applied on both heavy and light object). This is because your force (push) doesn’t gets converted *as it is* (I mean magnitude) into acceleration, it gets amplified or reduced. By some careful experiments our old ancestors found that *If a force $F$ is applied on an object and if that force produces an acceleration $a$ then $F$ is related to $a$ as $$ F = ma$$ where $m$ is the inertial mass of the object on which force was applied* .

Now, let’s do some mathematics with equation. Assume force of magnitude $F$ was applied on both light and heavy object, then for both of them we can write the equation separately as $$ F = m a_m \\
F = M a_M $$

$M$ is the inertial mass of the heavy object and $m$ is the mass of the lighter one. $$ a_m = \frac{F}{m} \\
a_M = \frac{F}{M} $$

You can see very clearly that $a_m \gt a_M$ (I wouldn’t try to explain it because over explanation sometimes ruins the whole understanding). So, a light object would have more speed and the heavy one will have less speed. Now, if the object in your question is lighter than you then it will be accelerating faster than you and since the same force acts on you (the force with which you pushed it was felt instantaneously by you) but your mass is bigger than that therefore your acceleration will be smaller than that object. It’s a very simple maths, *less mass $\times $ bigger acceleration* is same in magnitude as *big mass $\times$ low acceleration* .

The action-reaction law has nothing to do with acceleration of the objects. *Every action has an equal and opposite reaction* is an experimental result. Reaction of the force is felt because every object *distorts* a little whenever it is subjected to any force. This distortion causes the reaction force. In many cases you cannot see that distortion but it is there.

P.S. :- My explanation  of that reaction force is (the last paragraph of actual answer) was developed from the book **Newtonian Mechanics** by **A.P. French**.

Comment: I think the OP wants to know how the forward acceleration of the hand factors in

Comment: @BobD It may be that. What I have understood and inferred (from a naive mistake of acceleration part) that OP is trying to conclude 3rd law from the 2nd law, but 3rd Law is purely an experimental result.

Comment: @Knight How does the forward acceleration of the hand play a factor in this?

Comment: @Finn As soon as **you** accelerate your hand in forward direction for pushing the object, the reaction force from the object pushes you backward.

Comment: @Finn Please let me know which part of my answer is unclear to you.